# Submit songs based on Event name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a program where I can enter a song(artist, title, genre) based on a dropdown menu which holds all the databases event name. How could I pass the objects event name while also fulling the requirement of needing that events id to submit the song to that event. Here is my song_form:

```
<%= form_for @song do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :event_id, options_for_select(Event.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, @song.event_id), :class => 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.text_field :artist %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Song Controller:

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @song = Song.new
    end

    def create
        current_event = Event.find(params[:song][:event_id])
        @song = current_event.songs.build(song_params)
        if @song.save
            flash[:success] = "Success"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            flash[:error] = "Failed"
        end

    end

    def destroy
    end
    private

      def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:event_id, :artist, :title, :genre)
      end
end
```

Is there any way I can achieve this. I cannot submit a song to an event without it's id, it would be great if you guys could help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller's `new` action, define a instance variable `@song = Song.new` and use that variable in as `form` object. Thus, you can track the selected `Event` while editing the song. But if you create two separate view forms for `new` and `edit`, then it's ok.

```
<%= form_for @song do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :event_id, options_for_select(Event.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, @song.event_id), :class => 'form-control' %>
<% end %>
```

Check [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)

Comment: Thank you, one more thing. In my create action it's saying that there is no Event id being passed i will update my question with the song controller as well

Comment: access by `Event.find(params[:song][:event_id])` check if it gives you the `event_id` or not. Try to debug what's going on, put a rails console print. Also, check `Event` table whether any event is missing an ID or not

Comment: One last thing then I will accept your answer. When I create the @song variable in the new action in my controller it says that it is  null in the form, any reasons why this might be so?

Comment: @Aaron, Yes, it would be null. It'll just create an object of `Song` class. Thus, all the fields on `Song` table is initialized to whatever you've defined in your migration file. Better to see the rails docs for more detail. Your `Song.new` process is also right, actually it's as like as the variable. But we use `_form.html.erb` for both edit and create